# ZXing disable auto focus while scanning barcode

Tags: android, focus, barcode, zxing

I am really new in programming with Android
and i try to create a small app for scanning barcodes:

```
IntentIntegrator ii = new IntentIntegrator(a);
ii.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
ii.setPrompt("Scan a barcode");
ii.setCameraId(0);
ii.setBeepEnabled(true);
ii.initiateScan();
```

Its working but sometimes i have to wait "a long time (~seconds)" of the focusing android camera. How can i fix it?
Maybe disable focus or set a fix distance?

(ZXing 3.5.0, minSdkVersion 23, AndroidStudio)

Thanks for help.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/86) may help

Comment: **...barcodeView.getCameraSettings().setAutoFocusEnabled(false)...
...This has to be done with a custom activity currently, no option for it via the IntentIntegrator..**
Yes But i dont understand how to create activity for the barcode scanner.
Is there any tutorial or example?

Comment: Go through with [This library](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) . Its kind of awesome implementation of Zxing with customization